# How to handle an exception in a clean way in C++

Tags: c++, exception, coding-style, readability, throw

My problem is that I'm writing a program which is supposed to be readable for the future, and the program has a lot of exception cases. So whenever I have to throw an exception, I have to writer over 10 lines to initialize my exception class and append the information from the program to it. For example as follows:

```
MyExceptionClass ex;
ex.setErrorMessage("PIN_CANNOT_GO_IN");
ex.setErrorDetails("The pin is asked to go to the state IN while the depth of the r-coordinate does not support it");
ex.setResolutionMessage("Configure your coordinates-file to move first to the correct position before changing the state of the pin");
ex.VariableList().resize(5);
ex.VariableList()[0].push_back("Pin state: ");
ex.VariableList()[0].push_back(ToString(pin.getPinState()));
ex.VariableList()[1].push_back("Pin target state: ");
ex.VariableList()[1].push_back(ToString(coordinatesData[coordinatesIndex].targetPinState));
ex.VariableList()[2].push_back("Current r Value: ");
ex.VariableList()[2].push_back(ToString(EncoderPosition.r));
ex.VariableList()[3].push_back("Current phi Value: ");
ex.VariableList()[3].push_back(ToString(EncoderPosition.phi));
ex.VariableList()[4].push_back("Current z Value: ");
ex.VariableList()[4].push_back(ToString(EncoderPosition.z));

ex.printLog();
ex.writeLog(exceptionLogFilePath.getValue());

throw ex;
```

So for only 5 variables, I had to write all that...
Is there an efficient way to contain all information from the program (variables at least) and not rewrite all this every time I wanna throw an exception?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, construct objects with constructors, not a bunch of setters. That's what constructors are for. Second, your exception is a bunch of strings anyway, just format them together as one big nice user-presentable string and fire.

Comment: Hve you tried writing a function that generates the exception (that is, contains everything but the `throw` line), and just doing `throw exceptionGenerator()` or however you call that function?

Comment: How will the function have access to the list of variables in my program? this would mean I will have to pass them through parameters, and we're back to square one. Is there a way to have all variables added to my exception class automatically?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a common function (fill_out_exception_parameters) that fills out the VariableList object for a generic exception and re-use that in any new exception classes that you write

Comment: How will the function have access to the list of variables in my program? this would mean I will have to pass them through parameters, and we're back to square one. Is there a way to have all variables added to my exception class automatically?

Answer (score 2):

If the data added to the exception class is only used to display an error message, you could use string concatenation to reduce the number of `push_back()` used.

For example, you could use:

```
ex.VariableList()[0].push_back(string("Pin state: ") + ToString(pin.getPinState());
```

You could even concatenate all the other messages instead of using separate indices (1, 2, 3, 4, etc.) for each.

Moreover, for each field, you could use a dedicated setter method to feed the appropriate value. For example:

```
ex.VariableList()[0].setPinState(ToString(pin.getPinState()));
```

and then the `"Pin state: "` part should be moved to the place where the error message is *printed*.

---

Going even further, your exception class could have a dedicated method which accepts all the objects which contribute to the error message, and call that message instead. For example:

```
void MyExceptionClass::setMessage(Pin& pin, CoordinatesData& cd, EncoderPosition& ep) {
    setPinState(ToString(pin.getPinState()));
    // set whatever else you want here
}
```

Moreover, move the `ToString()` part to wherever the message is getting printed, just store the values in the exception class. For example, change the line above to (you need to change the signature accordingly):

```
setPinState(pin.getPinState());
```

and let the printing logic decide how to convert it to string. A further advantage is that it allows you to print the same message in different formats.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But I'm still looking for a cleaner way where all variables can be added automatically, and where all I have to do is write the error message, and expect the program to automatically handle the same variable name and the current value for multiple spots in the program, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @SamerAfach I think my updated answer comes pretty close to what you want. Play around with that a bit and let me know if that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Boost Exception to streamline adding arbitrary data to your exception objects, and to augment them with more relevant data as they bubble up the call stack. You won't have to worry about pre-defining everything you might need to store in exceptions, as you can literally store any data as needed to any exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the cleanest way to do it. Please let me hear what you think.

So I encapsulate all the relevant variables in a templatized class as follows (just a quick-and-dirty example)

```
class VarBase
{
VarBase();
static std::vector<VarBase*> __allParams;
string getStringValue() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Var : public VarBase
{
    T value;
    string name;
    string description;
    toString();
    operator T();
    string getStringValue();
};

VarBase::VarBase()
{
    __allParams.push_back(this);
}
VarBase::~VarBase()
{
    //handle removing from __allParams vector or whatever container
}
template <typename T>
std::string Var<T>::getStringValue()
{
    std::stringstream s;
    s << paramValue;
    return s.str();
}
```

Now if the my exception class is friends with the VarBase class, it can access __allParams and loop through that and call getStringValue() which will automatically do convert the value to a string and add it to my exception calss when necessary :)

Any additional ideas is highly appreciated.

Comment: Comments about the method?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks for your reply. Why is it not thread-safe? The vector __allParams needs to be access only when either creating a variable or throwing an exception, and you could use a map for storing points with unique IDs. And why is it not automated? The exception class will read all stored pointers and when the program crashes it can get all the information available from it. Right? Please explain your point.

Comment: It is not thread safe because a single vector is shared between threads without explicit synchronization (which is the text book definition of no thread safety). Regarding the automation, the only way to use `Var<T>` is to use it as a local variable (otherwise copies/assignment get in the way); since you might want to log parameters that are not `Var<T>` I had surmise its purpose was to capture references; may have been wrong though (and influenced by the way *I* would do it).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue: how does one *enrich* an exception with contextual information ?

Boost proposes one solution: `try/catch` and enrich the exception in the `catch` block before rethrowing it. It does enrich the exception, but not *automatically*.

The solution I came up with in the end is extremely simple, and based on C++ destructors strength. But first, how to use it:

```
void foo(int i) {
    LOG_EX_VAR(i);
    // do something that might throw
}
```

Yep, that's all, a single macro call and `i` is added to an exception context along with the function name, file name and line number the macro was expanded at.

What's behind ? The [most important const](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) and a bit of magic.

```
class LogVar {
public:
    LogVar(LogVar const&) = delete;
    LogVar& operator=(LogVar const&) = delete;

    virtual ~LogVar() {}

protected:
    LogVar();
}; // class LogVar

template <typename T>
class LogVarT: public LogVar {
public:
    LogVarT(char const* fc, char const* fl, int l, char const* n, T const& t):
        _function(fc), _filename(fl), _line(l), _name(n), _t(t) {}

    ~LogVar() {
        ContextInterface::AddVariable(_function, _filename, _line, _name, _t);
    }

private:
    char const* _function;
    char const* _filename;
    int _line;

    char const* _name;
    T const& _t;
}; // class LogVarT

template <typename T>
LogVarT make_log_var(char const* fc,
                     char const* fl,
                     int l,
                     char const* n,
                     T const& t)
{
    return LogVarT(fc, fl, l, n, t);
}

#define LOG_EX_VAR(Var_)                                                      \
    LogVar const& BOOST_PP_CAT(_5416454614, Var_) =                           \
        make_log_var(__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, #Var_, Var_);
```

This works fairly well, if you can get the difficult part (the `ContextInterface::AddVariable()` function) to work.

If you don't want to bother with it, then go for a `thread_local` `std::vector<LogVar*>` as you did. Just be aware that you'll be doing a lot of work for nothing.

If you are interested in it, then follow on.

1. Let's realize that the most important part here is to get something that is thread-safe. So the context will be global... per thread (aka `thread_local`). But even then one might accidentally leak a reference to it outside.
2. It is important to realize that several exceptions may coexist, though only one is uncaught at any point in time: that is an exception may be thrown within a `catch` clause.
3. We can only instrument the exceptions we throw ourselves, so we need some kind of default policy for the others. Logging, for example.

So, let's get the interface straight:

```
class ContextInterface {
public:
    typedef std::unique_ptr<ContextInterface> UPtr;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<ContextInterface> SPtr;
    typedef std::weak_ptr<ContextInterface> WPtr;

    static UPtr SetDefault(UPtr d) {
        std::swap(d, DefaultContext);
        return d;
    }

    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    static SPtr SetActive(Args&&... args) {
        SPtr ci = ExceptionContext.lock();
        if (ci.get()) { return ci; }

        ci.reset(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        ExceptionContext = ci;
        return ci;
    }

    template <typename T>
    static void AddVariable(char const* fc,
                            char const* fl,
                            int l,
                            char const* n,
                            T const& t)
    {
        SPtr sp = ExceptionContext.lock();
        ContextInterface* ci = sp.get();

        if (not ci) { ci = DefaultContext.get(); }

        if (not ci) { return; }

        ci->report(fc, fl, l, n) << t;
    }

    virtual ~ContextInterface() {}

private:
    static thread_local UPtr DefaultContext;
    static thread_local WPtr ExceptionContext;

    virtual std::ostream& report(char const* fc,
                                 char const* fl,
                                 int l,
                                 char const* n) = 0;
}; // class ContextInterface
```

And finally, the last missing piece (well, apart from the actual contexts you would want I guess): an example of the base exception class.

```
class ContextualException: public virtual std::exception {
public:
    ContextualException(): _c(ContextInterface::SetActive<ExceptionContext>()) {}

    ContextInterface const& context() const { return *_c; }

private:
    ContextInterface::SPtr _c;
}; // class ContextualException
```

Comment: I'll have to give your method a deeper thought.

Comment: @SamerAfach: Take your time, especially since I am not too sure about the latter part (the `AddVariable` implementation).

Comment: Thank you for the code. Let me see if I understand the purpose of your code correctly. So you're following exactly my approach, but the only difference is that you're introducing some kind of mutex on the shared parts? Can't I just use a home-made mutex for __allParams in my example?

Comment: @SamerAfach: actually, I am not exactly using your approach. 1/ Exceptions are local to a thread (up to a point), so it does not make sense to share the `__allParams` (a reserved identifier by the way) with other threads; it should be `thread_local` 2/ Your approach is pessimistic (I guess) in that you always register things in `__allParams` regardless of whether they are actually useful or not. My approach only register things in the "context" during a stack unwinding caused by an exception. Therefore, there is (almost) no penalty for exception-free executions....

Comment: @SamerAfach: [cont] 3/ Your approach seems to register instances of `VarBase` and only those. Mine instead let you instantiate whatever you want, and then asks you to identify those variables you'd like to appear in a stack dump of an exception explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Those textual descriptions should be linked to the exception class inherently, rather than written into each instance as runtime data.

Similarly, all that informational data should be members of the exception class, and you can format it for output as text later (perhaps in a member function of the exception class itself).